# Android: Unable to get localized region based strings

Tags: android, localization, region

I am unable to get localized region based strings.

I have a phone number that is based on the region or Country the user is in.

I have 5 different regions and 3 different languages. Language folders are values-es, values-en, values-ru. The 5 regions are values-en-rAU, values-en-rUS, values-es-rCL, values-es-rUY.

In my default values/strings.xml I have:

```
<string name="help_phone_number">(888)888—8888</string>
```

And in the others I have different numbers like

```
<string name="help_phone_number">(888)888—1111</string>
```

But it always displays the default string value. I am running my app in a emulator and changing the locale that way but also attempting to change it manually in the code as well since I thought it wasn't working with:

```
    @NonNull
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public static String getStringByLocal(Activity context, int id, String locale) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
        configuration.setLocale(new Locale(locale));
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration).getResources().getString(id);
    }
```

When I print out the locale it is correct. But the string is still displaying the default strings.

Comment: Have you seen the Custom Locale (app) tool available with the Android emulator?  Have you given that a try?

Comment: Indeed I have tried that as well and am still getting the same issue